# QGIS: Lines to polygons not working

Tags: qgis, polygonize

I have +1000 CityGML data with building height that I want to convert to a raster mask for deep learning. So far, I have converted the GML data into GeoJSON with its respective ID as linestring. Now I want to convert the polylines to polygons (QGIS: “lines to polygons”) but it is not correctly working:

[image]

I am well aware that similar questions exist on StackOverflow but none of the proposed solutions has worked for me. I tried the following:

1. Polygonize > works but **no** attributes are saved which I essentially need for the raster mask
2. Assign projection
3. Buffer lines with 0 m
4. Merge selected lines
5. Dissolved > the result is much better but it is still not working for all lines
   [image]
6. Extract vertices > points to the path
7. Identification of gaps as shown here ([Transforming lines to polygons not working in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232864/transforming-lines-to-polygons-not-working-in-qgis)) > gaps found
8. Select lines > join multiple lines plugin
9. Fix geometry (no errors found) > lines to polygons
10. Dissolve > fix geometry > lines to polygons (same result as 5)

I applied the workflow to a single file but need some sort of automation e.g. in Python since I have so many files. The files also contain geometries with “NULL” entries, which would need to be filtered out. The heights are stored in a separate csv file. I’m new to Python.

My test data (EPSG 25832) can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hGNFlrOyOXllKgFIy0thRfufcerNfWkh/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Sure! I added it to my post.

Answer (score 4):

1. Drop M/Z values
2. Polygonize
3. Join attributes by location to join the line attributes to the polygons

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried it but I still face the problem of 1) where the polygons miss the gml_id attributes which I need in order to identify the height information in the csv table. Also, I'm not sure on how to automatize this step.

Comment: Join the attributes by location. You can execute the model in [batch mode](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html) for all files. After you've pressed "Run model" there is a "Run as batch process" option