# Converting single line into polygon plane in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, convert

Is there a way to convert a line or multiple lines into polygon?

I have a feature attribute as with, and the line represents the road.
I want to convert every route into a polygon plane that somewhat looks like a road.

I think if line turns, then polygon will look disconnected. How to fix it, if possible?

Comment: You could try buffer https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_queries.html or polygonize https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/207463/convert-a-line-to-polygon?rq=1 depending on what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Michael use the Buffer option. It will create the polygon you require. The only thing u need to know is the width of the road. Different roads would have different width, so you might have to do it in batches, but then again its upto you if you want to keep a common width for all or go for different.